# Adding Up and Down Features to Bootstrap Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a function that allows me to add rows to a table, upwards or downwards. I'm working on the 'up' function right now, which in my opinion will be very similar to the down function. I'm using JavaScript/Jquery and the up arrow only appears after they have saved the row. Here's my code for the Save function and the in-progress up function that doesn't work.

```
function Save() { 
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr 
    var tdDate = par.children("td:nth-child(1)"); 
    var tdTime = par.children("td:nth-child(2)"); 
    var tdTreatmentNum = par.children("td:nth-child(3)"); 
    var tdCellNum = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");                             
    var tdWasteContNum = par.children("td:nth-child(5)");
    var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(6)");

    tdDate.html(tdDate.children("input[type=date]").val());
    tdTime.html(tdTime.children("input[type=time]").val());
    tdTreatmentNum.html(tdTreatmentNum.children('select').val());
    tdCellNum.html(tdCellNum.children('select').val());
    tdWasteContNum.html(tdWasteContNum.children('select').val());
    tdButtons.html("<img src='trash.png' class='btnDelete'/>
    <img src='pencil.png' class='btnEdit'/><img src='up.png'class='btnUp'/>"); 

    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit); 
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete); 
    $(".btnUp").bind("click", Up);

};

function Up() {
    var row = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    if ($(this).hasClass('up'))
        row.prev().before(row);
    else
        row.next().after(row);
});
```

I am not familiar with JQuery. My Add Row no longer works(though I know it functions properly). Here's a more complete code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46nozdqa/) for add, save, and up functions, including the html table. Any ideas?

> Updated - [Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46nozdqa/1/)

That helped, but it seems to just be moving the item to the bottom of the list, instead of up or even one down.

Comment: can we see the html too?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in a jsFiddle? That or include the table markup so we can try to reproduce it ourselves. As it stands currently, you haven't given us much to work on. *"Doesn't Work"* is pretty vague.

Comment: Sorry, I've attached the JSFiddle link, let me know if you need any other code

Comment: @Coleen I have updated your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46nozdqa/2/). I used the Bootstrap icons to show the action buttons. Everything seems pretty good. Can you look at the updated code and update your question if you still face any issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some issue in your JSFiddle that you have provided. I have updated your code and provided a working sample in the question itself.

since it wasn't possible to show the actual images you're using so I used the glyph icons of bootstrap library to display the similar images. You can replace the `<span>` tags with your `<img>` again in your development environment and everything should work fine.

This version of updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46nozdqa/3/) is working fine as you asked for `Delete` and on `Save`. Hope this will help you getting along.

Comment: Thanks so much, do you have any idea why the "up" is forcing the objects down, unless its the first entry on the list, which forces it to the bottom?

Comment: It's the order of the elements.. Look for the <span> with class glyph-arrow-up and down move them around to make first element in JS string. It should do the needful. @Coleen Mark it as answer if it helped you. So that other users knows that it solved the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed mark. Thanks again for the help. Bit new to this, what JS string? and should I still switch given I'm using actual images?

Comment: I meant JS string is simply expression that represents string e.g. var html="<span class='glyph glyph-class'></span>";